Questions about how to collect modules
Question Example
I have the following code:
import com.dd.plist.NSObject;
import com.dd.plist.XMLPropertyListWriter;
import org.gradle.api.Action;
import org.gradle.api.Transformer;
import org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException;
import org.gradle.internal.MutableActionSet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class PropertyListTransformer<T extends NSObject> implements Transformer<T, T> {
    private final MutableActionSet<T> actions = new MutableActionSet<T>();

    /**
     * Adds an action to be executed when property lists are transformed.
     * @param action the action to add
     */
    public void addAction(Action<? super T> action) {
        actions.add(action);
    }
}

I am trying to collect the import modules used in this code. Some of these modules don't seem to be available on GitHub or in the usual repositories. Where can I find them, or what are the correct dependencies I need to add?

Like https://github.com/3breadt/dd-plist? You neglect to mention what you can’t find (found dd.plist in 30 seconds by searching for it on the web)

Thanks for the reply. I think I am seriously lacking in exploration skills. What is the function of this process module?
